# Testflight Crash Reports don't show up

Tags: swift, testflight

I released an app to test users via testflight on iTunes Connect. One of my testers told me the app crashed, but I do not see any crashlog being generated that I could view in my organizer nor in itunes Connect. How can I debug this issue properly? I uploaded the archive with symbols and the correct version is being tested. Still there is not a report being sent to me.

Comment: Do you know where to find symbolicated crash reports in the Organizer of the machine you built and uploaded the app to TestFlight from?

Comment: is it the dsyms download button i need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I see on my side for a project I recently updated and pushed onto TestFlight.

The Xcode Organizer will show a "Crashes" tab along with Archives.

And in that Crashes tab, you can choose versions to look at from a popup menu.

[image: Crashes Appear In the Organizer]

Here's [more information about the Crashes organizer from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-crashes_organizer/AboutCrashesOrganizer/AboutCrashesOrganizer.html).

As you can see, I couldn't find a version of my app with any crashes.  Not to say that my code is perfect (ha ha), but I'm not 100% certain the TestFlight crash log downloading system is foolproof.  Perhaps this is the reason why so many developers choose to use more explicit Crash Reporting frameworks like Crashlytics or Fabric.

Comment: actually I decided to move to fabric/crashlytics

Comment: btw: Crashlytics / Fabric is awesome.. it was a very decent description of what I needed to know to fix the bug within 2 min. Really impressive system

Comment: results from apple products